# Git Repo Setup work locally on branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I have a repo setup, and am just learning about how branches work.  Right now I have two branches on the remote repo:
master
dev

It's a little bit confusing to have the same word checkout between git and svn, since in svn it means pull all the files, but in git it only means switch where the commits will go.

I tried to git clone before I created the dev branch, but when I tried to push from my local machine it gave me a message saying it wouldn't do it due to the index and tree getting messed up if I did it.

I want to work on dev on my local machine, and possibly diff and compare that to the master branch.  git clone didn't pull down the dev branch, only the master one.  How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `git clone` did fetch the master branch and check it out. You can now checkout the dev branch using `git checkout --track -b dev origin/dev` (checkout the branch `dev` from the remote `origin`, and create a new (local) branch called `dev` that tracks it).

Comment: hmm, so I do git branch and I only see master.  

So if I do git checkout --track -b dev origin/dev does that actually run out to the remote repository and ask for the additional info, or does it just pull from the local cloned copy?

Comment: Your "local" repo knows about the remote branches, but since there's no "local" version of the branch, `git branch` doesn't show it. `git branch -a` should however show it. The `checkout` command will get the dev branch from the remote and make a local version of it.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one clone of the repo to do what you are looking for.  While you are working in the dev branch you can compare your changes with any other branch.  For example to show a simple list of changes between dev and master you could do while in the dev branch:

```
git diff --stat master
```

If you want to see the actual changes between the two you can do:

```
git diff master
```

A lot of the commands will allow you to pass in branch names to do this type of functionality.